# Keyboard shortcut to cycle between opened editors in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> actually meant to do?

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to "Cycle Between Opened Editors".

Viewing the vscode Explorer, I can see that there are several "working files", but pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+` does nothing.

I miss being able to use the "standard" keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

(Note: I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does the job!)

Another problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is that the symbol is not easily accessible on, for example, a Norwegian keyboard layout. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open multiple documents side by side (<kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> in file list), this shortcut lets you switch between them.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.